# Maintain password for TFS Release Management

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015, release-management, ms-release-management

I'm developing Release pipeline for our internal LOB applications using TFS 2015 Update2 Release Management. There are various tasks like "Windows Machine File Copy" and "Run PowerShell on Target machines" which needs admin credentials to be passed as input parameters. These admin credentials have Administrative access on target nodes. I'm using Windows service accounts for these. We have an organizational security policy to rotate passwords every year.

With that in mind, it is cumbersome to update hundreds of TFS release definitions for new password every year.

Do you have a better idea to handle this?

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can update release definitions programmatically via the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions), which is well-documented and fairly straightforward.

Ex (note that this is for Update 3 and later, per the documentation, the API in TFS 2015.2 may differ slightly):

```
PUT https://fabfiber.vsrm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ff213d65-d61d-447c-b39d-d16f21b18364/_apis/release/definitions/28?api-version=3.0-preview.1
```

`Content-Type: application/json`

`{
  "id": 28,
  "name": "Fabrikam.CD",
  "createdOn": "2016-04-11T11:04:05.197Z",
  "createdBy": {
    "id": "52a5bc8d-4730-400a-95c7-7276d4ae5953",
    "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
    "uniqueName": "chuckreinhart@outlook.com",
    "url": "https://fabfiber.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities/52a5bc8d-4730-400a-95c7-7276d4ae5953",
    "imageUrl": "https://fabfiber.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=52a5bc8d-4730-400a-95c7-7276d4ae5953"
  },
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "Dev",
      "rank": 1,
      "deployStep": {
        "tasks": []
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": "52a5bc8d-4730-400a-95c7-7276d4ae5953",
        "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
        "uniqueName": "chuckreinhart@outlook.com",
        "url": "https://fabfiber.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities/52a5bc8d-4730-400a-95c7-7276d4ae5953",
        "imageUrl": "https://fabfiber.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=52a5bc8d-4730-400a-95c7-7276d4ae5953"
      },
      "queueId": 2,
      "demands": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "variables": {},
      "runOptions": {},
      "environmentOptions": {
        "emailNotificationType": "Always",
        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
        "timeoutInMinutes": 0
      },
      "executionPolicy": {
        "concurrencyCount": 0,
        "queueDepthCount": 0
      },
      "preDeployApprovals": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": true,
            "isNotificationOn": false
          }
        ],
        "approvalOptions": null
      },
      "postDeployApprovals": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": true,
            "isNotificationOn": false
          }
        ],
        "approvalOptions": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "FabrikamCI",
      "type": "Build",
      "definitionReference": {
        "project": {
          "name": "Fabrikam",
          "id": "ff213d65-d61d-447c-b39d-d16f21b18364"
        },
        "definition": {
          "name": "Fabrikam.CI",
          "id": "1"
        }
      },
      "isPrimary": false
    }
  ],
  "variables": {},
  "triggers": [],
  "revision": 1,
  "releaseNameFormat": "",
  "retentionPolicy": {
    "daysToKeep": 60
  }
}`

Comment: sorry been dragged into other stuff. The variable holding pwd is returned as

Comment: The variable holding pwd is returned as 
"variables": {
        "AppPoolIdentityName": {
          "value": "svc-account"
        },
        "AppPoolIdentityPassword": {
          "value": null,
          "isSecret": true
        }

Now picture I have 2 variables which are secret. However with my REST Api Update call, I need to update one of them. How that looks? Do I need to include every thing in my Update call or just my changes like in Patch.