# Team Foundation Server(Release Pipeline)

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm developing Release pipeline for deploying artefacts using TFS 2017 Update3 Release Management. There are various tasks like "Windows Machine File Copy" and "Run Power Shell on Target machines" which needs admin credentials to be passed as input parameters. These admin credentials have Administrative access on target nodes. I'm using Windows service accounts for these. We have an organisational security policy to rotate passwords every month.

With that in mind, it is hectic to update hundreds of TFS release definitions for new password every month.

Do you have a better idea to handle this? Please give detailed answers.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `variable group` to store values that you want to make available across multiple build and release definitions. Variable groups are defined and managed in the **Library** tab of the **Build & Release** hub. In this way, you can just edit the variable group:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks Cece, I was looking for a easy solution and you gave exactly what I needed. It worked like charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the process you use the solution defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148302/maintain-password-for-tfs-release-management.). This details how to use the TFS API to poke the definitions.

Alternatively you could create your own PowerShell task that sources the password from some alternative source like Azure Key vault or even hard code it into the json task definition itself (don't do this).

You can vote to improve this story [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31232884-vsts-build-powershell-on-target-machine-default-us).

I wrote a custom version of the PowerShell task that uses the identity of the agent as part of the WinRM session which greatly simplifies our release definition process.

Comment: thanks Michael for swift reply. I am running some power shell scripts to deploy artefacts to the tools installed on target server and running some task which simply copies artefacts to the target server i.e copy-paste

Comment: If you want to automate the process you use the solution defined here. This details how to use the TFS API to poke the definitions. In this link it is said to use rest api but i don't know about rest api. Could you please explain it in more eeasy way. Like how to implement the rest api for the whole process.

Comment: I have no idea what your background or experience is so that is impossible. You can invoke REST APIs without much ceremony from PowerShell if you use Windows.

Comment: Consider also that TFS 2018 introduced the concept of Deployment Group that dramatically reduce the number of credentials to manage. I would favor investing in an upgrade.